# Too many types in declaration C++

Tags: c++, variables, modifiers

When **unsigned/signed long int a;** is possible
why **unsigned/signed long float/double a;** is not possible ?

Why do I get ***too many types in declaration*** error for the latter and not for the former ?

Comment: Because there is not an unsigned float?

Comment: `error: 'signed' or 'unsigned' invalid for 'a'` &  `error: 'long' invalid for 'a'`

Answer (score 1):

There are three floating point types: `float`, `double` and `long double`. None of these have unsigned equivalents, so putting `signed` or `unsigned` in front of them is not valid. There is no such type as `long float`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that message because a long double exists, but an unsigned long double does not. unsigned can also be interpreted as an int, therefore you possess two types in the latter declaration: *unsigned* and *long double*. I do not believe there is a long float in C++.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the first (`long int`) is a documented variable type, while the second isn't.

The data types that the C++ language supports are:

```
char         
unsigned char   
signed char     
int            
unsigned int    
signed int  
short int 
unsigned short int 
signed short int
long int    
signed long int 
unsigned long int 
float   
double  
long double
```